# f-strings giving SyntaxError: invalid syntax?

Tags: python, string, syntax-error, python-3.7, string-interpolation

I'm trying to learn Python and I'm getting a syntax error message in Sublime Text while trying to run this f-string code

Code:

```
 # print welcome message
 greeting = 'Hello'
 name = 'Michael'
 message = f'{greeting}, {name}. Welcome!'
 
 print(message)
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/stevie/Desktop/intro.py"]
[dir: /Users/stevie/Desktop]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `python 3.7`?

Comment: try executing `import sys; print(sys.version)` in the script to double check.

Comment: I was actually running 2.7. I ran the code in 3.7 and it worked

Comment: **Your code seems right !** It could be the python version. Remember that `f-strings` interpolation is available only since **3.7**

Comment: @Juan-Kabbali since 3.6, in fact.